# Is there any mobile emulator for showing demo on website?

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, emulation, demo

I developed j2me, android and blackberry based applications. I need to showing the demo for clients through my own website. Is there any mobile emulator for showing the demo for my application through website?.

For example user can choose the both type of mobile and type of application and then see the demo on website. Like Nokia RDA devices. Give me some idea for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for j2me, why dont you try [microemulator](http://www.microemu.org/demo.html)?

Comment: Do you know how to integrate?

Comment: It is well documented in this page.http://www.microemu.org/applet.html It seems that you got to include the applet jar file as well as your application jar file, and then specify the main class of your midlet with a parameter named "midlet". as in                                                    <applet code="org.microemu.applet.Main"
                width=226 height=471 archive="microemu-javase-applet.jar,(MIDlet application jar)">
        <param name="midlet" value="(MIDlet application main class)">
</applet>

Answer (score 3):

Record a video directly off the device or emulator and put that on your website.

The emulators will not really replicate the feel of an actual device at all. E.g. the android emulator has very different performance and issues (e.g. performance with video, usage of gps, general performance in terms of io vs cpu) and potentially this demo mode will do more harm than good to your sales, since the trial users might think it sucks on the demo already .. so the real thing must be worse.

Offer a trial version of the apps for free for download from market or wherever in addition if you have to.

Also get management to tell you why they need it on the website and see if that need cant be fulfilled better in a different way.

Comment: Yeah u r right. I already discussed, but management feel like this. They said directly showing demo on mobile emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Both [userzoom](http://www.userzoom.com/mobile-interface-testing) and [mobilexweb](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators) have some useful offerings.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be possible for J2ME, because it's a subset of J2SE and you can integrate this into an applet, but I don't think that'll be possible for Android, as it uses a different VM.

Comment: We already developed website by using asp.net. Is it possible to integrate with this one?

Comment: For J2ME, Yes, as a java applet running on client's browser. I dont know whether there are any android VM implementations in java applet format.